# java - What benefits can delegation to private static methods have over private methods in a springboot webflux (functional program style)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a question regarding the use of private static methods in the context of a java springboot webflux project.

Let me put some code first:

The straightforward codes of a spring project: a Main class, a Configuration class found under a config package, a Repository class found under the package repository, a Service interface found under the service package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Value("${someConfiguration}")
    private String someConfiguration;

    public String getSomeConfiguration() {
        return someConfiguration;
    }

}

@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends Reactive[...]Repository<String, String> { }

public interface SomeService {

    Mono<String> someCompute(String string);

}
```

(The question is not on above)

Now, as the implementation of the service layer: First, a version where the public facing method is delegating all computations to subsequent **private static methods**, passing the fields as parameter. (option 1)

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    private final SomeConfiguration someConfiguration;
    private final SomeRepository    someRepository;
    private final WebClient         webClient;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(SomeConfiguration someConfiguration, SomeRepository someRepository, WebClient webClient) {
        this.someConfiguration = someConfiguration;
        this.someRepository = someRepository;
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<String> someCompute(String string) {
        Mono<String> s1Mono = sendHttpRequestToSomewhere(webClient);
        Mono<String> s2Mono = s1Mono.map(x -> computeSomethingWithConfiguration(x, someConfiguration));
        Mono<Object> s3Mono = s2Mono.map(x -> saveToSomewhere(x, someRepository));
        return s3Mono.map(x -> computeSomethingElse(x));
    }

    private static Mono<String> sendHttpRequestToSomewhere(WebClient webClient) {
        return webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

    private static String computeSomethingWithConfiguration(String x, SomeConfiguration someConfiguration) {
        return x + someConfiguration.getSomeConfiguration();
    }

    private static Mono<String> saveToSomewhere(String x, SomeRepository someRepository) {
        return someRepository.save(x);
    }

    private static String computeSomethingElse(Object x) {
        return x.toString();
    }

}
```

As opposed to using the fields directly in a private **but non-static** method. (option 2)

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    private final SomeConfiguration someConfiguration;
    private final SomeRepository    someRepository;
    private final WebClient         webClient;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(SomeConfiguration someConfiguration, SomeRepository someRepository, WebClient webClient) {
        this.someConfiguration = someConfiguration;
        this.someRepository = someRepository;
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<String> someCompute(String string) {
        Mono<String> s1Mono = sendHttpRequestToSomewhere();
        Mono<String> s2Mono = s1Mono.map(x -> computeSomethingWithConfiguration(x));
        Mono<Object> s3Mono = s2Mono.map(x -> saveToSomewhere(x));
        return s3Mono.map(x -> computeSomethingElse(x));
    }

    private Mono<String> sendHttpRequestToSomewhere() {
        return webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

    private String computeSomethingWithConfiguration(String x) {
        return x + someConfiguration.getSomeConfiguration();
    }

    private Mono<String> saveToSomewhere(String x) {
        return someRepository.save(x);
    }

    private String computeSomethingElse(Object x) {
        return x.toString();
    }

}
```

(putting them together)

[image: together]

Question:

What are the benefits option 1 can bring?

This is a technical question, not opinion based. I am sure there is more than just code style preferences. I am seeing more and more projects adopting option 1 in the context of java webflux functional programs.

- What are the benefits in terms of compile time performance option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of runtime performance option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of thread safety option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of testability option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of mocks option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of maintainability option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are the benefits in terms of readability option 1 have or lack over option 2?
- What are other benefits option 1 have or lack over option 2 please?

Thank you

Comment: Your bullet list of questions is too broad, but ignore "compile-time performance" always, ignore "runtime performance" until you have a demonstrated problem (as long as you aren't being grossly inefficient like concatenating `String`s in a loop), and in general narrow down your question. Note that using static methods for pure functions is a good idea in general as it helps avoid certain programmer mistakes like incorporating state where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis for your comment. May I ask why it is too broad? I narrowed down the question to specific bullets. Furthermore, I think it is not a bad idea to ask question about performance to help a design in the first place. What do you think?

Comment: Hi Pat, questions on Stack Overflow should focus on and ask one thing. In this question, you've not only asked something that could be construed as opinion-based, but you've asked *nine* questions, not one. Any one of the nine questions could probably be a very long answer. That is why the question is too broad as it currently exists.

Comment: No problem. The answer I got was clear enough. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this question is related to WebFlux and to Spring in general, but rather to any code written in a functional style (you'll face the same with java 8 streams) and even to a code written in a "traditional" imperative style: what to call private static or private method?

In general I can see only one difference between private static methods and private methods:

**private non-static methods can access the state/dependencies (non static data fields) of the class, whereas *private static* methods can't**

This means that you might want to use private `static methods` if:

- You only use them within the class
- You want to emphasize that the method doesn't depend (read doesn't access) the internal state of the object its defined in.

On the opposite, if you already maintain the state/dependency, like `WebClient` in the example, then using the `static` makes you passing this parameter to the method. In My Opinion this is unnecessary: what if you have not 1, but say 3 parameters to pass and you call this method from many places in the source class.

Other than that I don't see much difference:

- Mocks (testing) is just the same because you don't test private methods anyway and you can mock your dependencies in both cases in a same way by using constructor injection or some advanced techniques of mockito.
- Performance penalty - roughly the same, I can't think about the case where the usage of one method over another will be a source of performance issues.
- Maintainability - again, depends on your usecase, if the method is accessing the internal state you better use non static variant to reduce the clutter, if you want to emphasize that you use a "util" method that doesn't depend on the state - use `private static` method.
- Multithreading - you should synchronize the state in both cases if its required, the fact that the method has `static` modifier by itself doesn't deal with multithreading at all.

I've also found [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234412/why-have-private-static-methods) that can be useful for this question, again its applicable for general programming style (code organization) not only for webflux.